# mysqli_connect returning null after successful connection

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working in php to grab, change, and insert data into different tables in MySQL and have ran into a bit of trouble. I create an initial connection to one table of my database with mysqli_connect

```
$dbh_phone = @mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "tablename",3306);

if (mysqli_connect_errno($dbh_phone)) {
     $err_params['sql_error'] = mysqli_connect_error($dbh_asterisk
     printf("Connect to asterisk database failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error($dbh_asterisk));
     exit();
}
```

I do what I need to regarding all the data I get from that table and save it into arrays to use. Then I move on to closing that connection and opening another so I can insert the data into a different table on a different schema on that same connection.

```
mysqli_close($dbh_calls);
unset($dbh_calls);

if (!isset($dbh_sales)) {
    $dbh_sales = @mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", TRUE, "newtablename", 3306);     
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($dbh_sales)) {
        $err_params['sql_error'] = mysqli_connect_error($dbh_sales);
        print $err_params['sql_error'];
        printf("Connect to sales database failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
```

This second connection is being returned as a NULL value even though it is successfully connecting and I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything correctly. I've added a TRUE between the password and the table in the second connection as I had read that would make things work when I had trouble connecting successfully with this connection. But, as I stated previously, this is now returning NULL making it impossible to insert my new data into this second table.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need a new connection. You can just use `mysqli_select_db()` to change the default database of the connection.

Comment: You're unsetting `$dbh_calls`, but you're testing `if(isset($dbh_sales))`.

Comment: And the first block of code used `$dbh_phone`. Why all the different variables?